Microsoft Graph API Authorization Error: 'Invalid size of Code_Challenge parameter.'
I am trying to generate an access token via a PKCE flow to call the Microsoft Graph API.
I am following this msdoc : Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Docs
But I am getting error like below:
AADSTS501491: Invalid size of Code_Challenge parameter.

To generate code_challenge, I am using below PHP code in reference to the above documentation.
The code_challenge generated by my code is 43 characters, which is the same string as the value generated by this tool using the same code_verifier, what is wrong?
For testing, I directly stored the value generated by the above tool in $codeChallenge in the following code and got the same error.

public function generateUrl()
{
    // cf. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7636#section-4
    $codeVerifier = $this->generateCodeVerifier();
    $codeChallenge = $this->generateCodeChallenge($codeVerifier);

    $fields = [
        'tenant'                => $tenantId,
        'client_id'             => $client_id,
        'redirect_uri'          => $redirect_uri,
        'response_type'         => 'code',
        'response_mode'         => 'query',
        'scope'                 => 'User.Read Directory.Read.All Group.Read.All GroupMember.Read.All',
        'code_challenge'        => $codeChallenge,
        'code_challenge_method' => 'S256',
    ];
    
    $baseUrl   = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize";

    return $baseUrl . '?' . http_build_query($fields);
}

private function generateCodeVerifier() {
    $randomString = random_bytes(32);
    $urlSafeString = strtr(base64_encode($randomString), '+/', '-_');
    return rtrim($urlSafeString, '=');
}

private function generateCodeChallenge($codeVerifier) {
    $hashedVerifier = hash('sha256', $codeVerifier, true);
    $urlSafeString = strtr(base64_encode($hashedVerifier), '+/', '-_');
    return rtrim($urlSafeString, '=');
}

